# Dynamic response with tracking pixels?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0, tracking

I am testing out some tracking pixel functionality in an ASP.Net 4 MVC architecture.

[This article](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/06/10/773.aspx) gives a nice way of setting a tracking pixel (image) that you can use to read a visitor's environment parameters and do some logging on the server side before completing the response.

What I would like to do is inject some Javascript, based on the account ID that the pixel came from.  In the example above, the ID would be set by setting some query string parameters.

By the looks of that code, it can only be used to log data, as the response type is of type image.

Is it possible to accomplish this using the method shown above?  If not, can I get some recommendations/sources on how to accomplish this using Javascript and tying this back into my .Net architecture where based on some logic, I can add some additional Javascript to the response?

If I have no other choice to go the JS route, I'm guessing it would be something along the lines of the Google Analytics tracking script that includes some parameters sent back through JS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the client is requesting an image and expecting an image, then that is what you need to return.  Look at this type of HTML that would generate an image request:

```
<img src="test.jpg">
```

Clearing the client is expecting image bits to come back and anything besides that is going to mess up the display of that image.

If you want to put server-supplied javascript into the page, then simply have the client request some javascript like this:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Your server can then do it's logging upon that request and return whatever javascript it wants to from that request.  If you want to return different javascript for every request, then you will need to defeat caching in the browser (there are a number of was to do that) so that the javascript is always requested from the server.

In general, I'm guessing that you don't need to return different javascript for every request.  But rather, you can put a common block of javascript in the client page and that javascript can examine the environment and branch based upon what it finds.  That's how Google Analytics works.  One common piece of javascript is served to the client, that code examines the environment and then makes an ajax request with different parameters set that causes the right information to be recorded on the server.